# Trying to copy custom fields' values from related list on the same custom fields on Opportunity object

Tags: apex, trigger

I looked for similar topics and used some best answers to modify my code, but it is still not populating the custom fields on Opportunity every time the custom fields on related list Property are entered. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Here is the class:

```
public with sharing class PropertyEscrowContactOnExchange {
public static void copyPropertyEscrowAddressOnExchange(List<Property__c> propList) {

    Set<String> oppIds = new Set<String>();

    for (Property__c prop : propList) {
        oppIds.add(prop.Id);
    }
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id, Name, Escrow_Company__c, Escrow_Address__c, Escrow_City__c, Escrow_State__c, Escrow_Zip_Code__c
                                        FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppIds];

    Map<String, Opportunity> oppByStrings = new Map<String, Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity o : opportunities){
        oppByStrings.put(o.Escrow_Company__c + o.Escrow_Address__c + o.Escrow_City__c + o.Escrow_State__c+ o.Escrow_Zip_Code__c, o);
    }

    for (Property__c p : propList) {
        Opportunity o = oppByStrings.get(p.Id);
        if (o == null && oppByStrings.containsKey(p.Id) && oppByStrings.get(p.Id).Properties__r.size()>0) {
            p.Escrow_Company__c = o.Escrow_Company__c;
            p.Escrow_Address__c = o.Escrow_Address__c;
            p.Escrow_City__c = o.Escrow_City__c;
            p.Escrow_State__c = o.Escrow_State__c;
            p.Escrow_Zip_Code__c = o.Escrow_Zip_Code__c;
        }
    }
}}
```

And Trigger:

```
trigger copyPropEscrowAddressOnExchange on Property__c (after insert, after update) {
if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
    PropertyEscrowContactOnExchange.copyPropertyEscrowAddressOnExchange(Trigger.new);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries and your `oppByStrings` do not do what you want.

```
for (Property__c prop : propList) {
    oppIds.add(prop.Id);
}
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id, Name, Escrow_Company__c, Escrow_Address__c, Escrow_City__c, Escrow_State__c, Escrow_Zip_Code__c
                                    FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppIds];
```

This query is locating Opportunities by comparing the Opportunity's Id to a `Set` containing only `Property__c` Ids. That will always return no rows at all.

Then, you're iterating over the results and populating a Map with a compound key:

```
    oppByStrings.put(o.Escrow_Company__c + o.Escrow_Address__c + o.Escrow_City__c + o.Escrow_State__c+ o.Escrow_Zip_Code__c, o);
}
```

But then accessing it by Id, which is not what's in the key set:

```
    Opportunity o = oppByStrings.get(p.Id);
```

You have two real options here. One is, if there is a relationship between Opportunity and Property, to use the actual Opportunity Id to query. Simplify to use a regular sObject map:

```
for (Property__c prop : propList) {
    oppIds.add(prop.Opportunity__c);
}

Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunities = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Name, Escrow_Company__c, Escrow_Address__c, Escrow_City__c, Escrow_State__c, Escrow_Zip_Code__c
                                    FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppIds]);


for (Property__c p : propList) {
    Opportunity o = opportunities.get(p.Opportunity__c);
```

The other, if you're going to use this compound-key approach, is to turn your `Set<Id>` into a `Set<String>` and populate it with the concatenation of those string fields you're interested in, then query on that basis. You'd need to make sure that *all* uses of your Map consistently use this compound key.

But that's not really a stable approach in most cases. For one thing, there's no guarantee that that field combination is unique or that it matches across objects - you're trying to mirror changes, after all, and that won't work unless you use `Trigger.oldMap` to get the *pre-change* values of those fields.

Ideally, you should just establish a relationship between these objects and write a nice simple trigger, or just use formula fields.